# Web timeline : No default view of type 'timeline' could be found

Tags: odoo, project, timeline

I uninstalled the "Web timeline" after that I can't get into my project I got this error what should I do please

Note: I've reinstalled, and I'm getting the same error

[image]

Comment: There probably is something left on the action of the menu you're clicking. Try to get into the menu settings (Settings/technical...), find the menu, open it, open the action and in the end fix the action.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah-1YJdhqAzihecIDGUwsmr7PGXEsg?e=Qlayn0
See what I got, don't know what to do next?

Comment: Search those actions under the other actions menu. It's called something like "window-open actions". There you will see more settings on the actions. (i thinks it's the menu right after the "Actions" menu)

Comment: Thanks for your time, did you know which one?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah-1YJdhqAzihecMyoNvI3EwpM5IUw?e=ydjQO7

Comment: I deleted all the "timeline" in view mode, and it works, but I don't understand why it doesn't know it when reinstalling

Comment: I found the solution when I reinstalled, I have to install this triple modules
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah-1YJdhqAzihecQp7ICcpMQ6wYE3w?e=Of7wRw